# MonoTouch, ZXing: Presenting ZXingScannerViewController failed

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, xamarin, zxing

So in the beginning of my application users have to ability to scan a QR-code. In the app settings the user can scan another barcode to change some data within the settings.

In the beginning of my application scanner works just fine but when I try to scan a barcode within the settingsVC I get the following Warning:

```
Warning: Attempt to present ZXing.Mobile.ZXingScannerViewController: 0x18036dc0 on UINavigationController: 0x16d8afe0 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I already tried to invoke the scan on `viewDidAppear` but I get the same warning.

```
            button_ScanAPI.TouchUpInside += async (sender, e) => {
                var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner ();
                var result = await scanner.Scan ();

                if (result != null) {
                    textField_APIKey.Text = result.Text;
                }   
            };
```

**EDIT:**

Tried to use the barcode scanner without async but I still get the same msg.

```
var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner ();
                scanner.Scan (true).ContinueWith (t => {   
                    if (t.Result != null) {

                        InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                            textField_APIKey.Text = t.Result.Text;

                        });
                    }
                });
```

And I also tried using AVFoundation resulting in the same error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <AVCaptureScannerViewController: 0x16fb1d00> on <UINavigationController: 0x16ebe790> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

**EDIT2:**

This is a part of the flow within my app.

[image]

Comment: What is the version target? Are you developing for iOS 7+?

Comment: If you use async, you must switch to a UI thread before creating the mobilebarcodescanner controller. => don't use async/await here. Instead use a continuation task on scanner.Scan

Comment: @dcorbatta Yes IOS 7+ is indeed the developing target.

Comment: @Softlion Ok, I will try this asap :)

Comment: @Softlion See my edit on the question. Still receive the same msg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can scan QR natively. In iOS 7 AVFoundation is capable to scan QR.
Take a look to the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

And [here](http://www.knowing.net/index.php/2013/10/09/natively-recognize-barcodesqr-codes-in-ios-7-with-xamarin-ios/) there is an example using Xamarin.

Answer (score 6):

I think that by default the ZXing library must be looking to your most top level NavigationController and tries to present the modal view controller from there. Like you, I have modally presented another NavigationController over the top of the root one. I was able to fix this by changing the constructor to:

```
var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner (this);
var result = await scanner.Scan ();
```

where "this" is the ViewController from which you are actually calling the scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Do either of these work:

1. Show your `settingsVC` without animation, i.e. from the VC that presents `settingsVC`:

   ```
   [self presentViewController:settingsVC 
                      animated:NO 
                    completion:nil];
   ```

   or

   ```
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:settingsVC 
                                        animated:NO];
   ```
2. Use a delay before showing the scanner, e.g. in `settingsVC`:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
       [super viewDidAppear:animated];

       NSTimeInterval delay = 0.3;
       [self performSelector:@selector(showScanner)
                  withObject:nil 
                  afterDelay:delay];
   }

   - (void)showScanner
   {
       // Show scanner here.
   }
   ```

Comment: No this still does not display the scannerVC and returns the same warning.

Comment: I almost replicated your issue assuming your settingsVC is actually a UINavigationController and initializing a zxing view controller on the settingsVC viewDidLoad. However, when initializing the zxing controller within viewDidAppear, as @JosephChen mentioned in his answer, made the problem go away and the scan controller appeared normally.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide additional info on what kind, how and where your settingsVC is setup, and if it is a UINavigationController the controllers you push upon it. Finally, I'd like to know how you initialize the zxing controller in the beginning of your app.

Comment: @DonMiguel I added a picture to clarify the location of my VC. In the beginning of my app i use the async / await method.

Comment: From your edit, I assume that your settings VC is a UITabBarController containing a UINavigationController on one of its tabs. You also have one UITableViewController at the root of the UINavigationController. You then push one more UITableViewController on that navigation stack, which invokes the zxing controller. Is that correct?